# What is the best way for distributed conflict resolution during merge in git? (deliberate partial commit)

Tags: git, merge, git-merge-conflict

Assume the following:

1. A team of several designers (DesignerA,DesignerB,DesignerC ...).
2. Main branch `master`
3. Two feature branches `featureA`, `featureB`.
4. In featureA:
   4.1. DesignerA Modified `./fileA`.
   4.2. DesignerB Modified `./fileB`.
   4.3. DesignerC Modified `./fileC`.
5. In featureB:
   5.1. DesignerA Modified `./fileA`.
   5.2. DesignerB Modified `./fileB`.
   5.3. DesignerC Modified `./fileC`.
6. DesignerC merges `featureA` + `featureB` into `master`:
   6.1. merge `featureA` to `master`:
   `fileA`,`fileB` and `fileC`'s changes are automatically merged.

   6.2. merge `featureB` to `master`:
   `fileC`'s conflict resolved by DesignerC
   `fileA`+`fileB` are conflicted but DesignerA owns fileA and DesignerB owns fileB.

My question:

**How can DesignerC pass the partially merged commit and let each designer to solve his own conflicts?**

say:

- Send to designerA :

  - resolved `fileC`
  - unresolved `fileA` - to handle
  - unresolved `fileB` - to leave unresolved
- Send to designerB :

  - resolved `fileC`
  - unresolved `fileA` - to leave unresolved
  - unresolved `fileB` - to handle
- Merge resolutions and push to master.

NOTE:

- The team tries to use git as simply as possible - please avoid fancy gitting in answers :)
- The solution of [temporary branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718477/how-to-manage-a-code-merges-on-git-with-multiple-users) is not the one I am looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manage a code merges on git with multiple users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718477/how-to-manage-a-code-merges-on-git-with-multiple-users)

Comment: Thanks, but the solution of temporary branches is not the one I am looking for.
I am looking for a way of committing unresolved conflicts which may be solved by other members in my team after pulling in their station.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63631045/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-a-monorepo/63695202#63695202) fit your need ? if that part looks ok, you can then combine the partial merges into one single merge commit (note : fancy-ish git commands involved ... ;) ).

Comment: Have to disagree with @torek here, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47835297/1290731) is a straightforward way to do it: everybody merge what they can, then merge the partial-merge results. See the link. Don't try to do this serially, that's just muddying the tasks each team's asked to do.

Answer (score 1):

#### There is no good way to do this

That doesn't mean you can't do it at all, but all ways that you *can* do it are currently rather bad.  The fundamental problem is simple, and has three or more parts depending on how you count:

- You can only push *commits*.
- Conflict resolution takes place in Git's index.
- New commits are made from Git's index.
- You can't make a new commit until you resolve all the conflicts.

Users may use their working tree files, and/or additional files inserted into their working tree or anywhere else, to help out with the resolving, but fundamentally, a conflict exists *because* Git has modified its index such that some entry is marked "conflicted".  To un-mark the entry—so that you can make a new commit, provided that this was the *last* conflict—you must resolve the conflict.

Hence, to make a commit that you can send to someone else so that they can resolve *their* part of the conflict, you must first resolve *all* parts of the conflict.  Now you can commit and send the commit and they can ... uhhhmmmm ... undo your resolution of their parts of the conflict?  Except, there's no conflict left.

#### Git *could* do this, if only you could commit a conflict

Unfortunately, you can't commit a conflict.  But all the *tools* exist within the Git ecosystem.  Conflicts exist because Git's index has non-zero-stage index entries.  The user's working tree also has tracked and/or untracked files that may represent partial resolutions.  If we could just take each of these—the non-zero-stage entries, and the tracked and untracked files—and make commits out of them and then use those commits to *re-assemble* the conflicted index and work-tree contents later, we'd have the makings of exactly what you want.

The `git ls-files --stage` output shows everything that is actually in Git's index.  We just need to write a program that takes this output and creates multiple separate temporary indices (that, each, aren't conflicted but allow another program to build a new conflicted index later) and commits those, along with another commit or two to save the work-tree state.  This mass of commits—however many are needed to save the stage 0, 1, 2, and 3 entries<sup>1</sup> plus the work-tree state—would probably be best represented as a faked-up merge, a la `git stash`, and then indexed via some reference for temporarily resolved states that can be restored to resume merging later, a la `refs/stash` for `git stash`.

The similarities to `git stash` are clear enough, and the implementation would likely borrow from the old `git stash` shell script to some extent.  The exact format for these commits, and the ref or refs to use, will require some thought and experimentation.

This command does not exist today.

---

<sup>1</sup>In theory, when there are conflicted entries at stage 1 in the index for instance, there could be more than one file with some specific name, such as `path/to/file.ext`.  This would represent multiple merge bases.  In practice Git doesn't seem to make use of this, and if it did, it is not clear how one would know which version of `path/to/file.ext` went with which merge base: would every file that has a stage-1 entry have to have N such entries, where N is the number of merge bases?  What hash value would go in the index slot if, say, merge base #1 has no file named `path/to/file.ext`, but merge base #2 does?

This all affects the design of the in-progress-merge "merge commit" we would make for handling this.

Answer (score 0):

Using git alone : you can't share a conflict, the solutions I have in mind involve creating temporary branches to let each designer fix its part independently, then combine these changes together.

---

Other solutions :

- have the three designers work on one same clone of the repo (e.g : physically walk over to one's office, remotely connect to a workstation, work on a common ssh machine ...)
- if the amount of files is low (one file per designer as in your example ?), send a copy of the "base/ours/theirs" versions of said files, and ask to send back the resolution